# Why does a memory leak occur in this code when a bad_alloc exception is thrown for T2

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

If T2 were to throw, why would this cause T1 to have a memory leak?

//  In some header file:
void f( T1*, T2* );

//  At some call site:
f( new T1, new T2 );

Comment: While I attempted a guess of an answer below, you're going to need to post more code. Specifically, a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

If the second object's constructor throws an exception, then `f()` won't get called, so the code inside `f()` won't have any chance to either delete the first object that was created, or to store a pointer to that object for later deletion.

Similarly, the code that might execute after the exception is raised (e.g. in any `catch` handler-block that you might have set up to handle the exception) will not have access to a pointer to either object, so it won't be able to delete the created object either.

Therefore, it's more-or-less(*) inevitable that the object will leak in that scenario.

(Note that it is unspecified which function-argument will get evaluated first, so it could just as easily be `T1()` that throws after a `T2` is created, causing a `T2` object to get leaked instead)

(*) I suppose you could do something crazy like having the final line in your `T1()` and `T2()` constructors store their `this`-pointers into a static data-structure somewhere, but that would be really ugly and introduce a number of other problems; the proper solution to this problem would be to use `std::unique_ptr` or similar to "capture" the objects so that an explicit `delete` call is never necessary, and therefore no memory leak is possible regardless of when an exception gets thrown.